# Struct array data in the first index is reset for some ATmega 2560

Tags: c++, arrays, json, struct, atmega

I have 3 exactly same PCB's accommodating ATmega2560 MCU. 
I'm using Atmel Studio 7 for fuses and flashing the HEX.
I'm using Visual Studio with Visual Micro plug-in using a mix of C and Arduino coding.

I have a struct array definition. I populate data into this struct array from a json fed by Serial port of the MCU. Json parser is ArduinoJson.

**Definitions**:

```
#define MAX_RECORDS 20 //Max number of records in the struct

typedef struct Record {
    uint8_t id;//unique number to define data sequence
    uint8_t sec;
    uint8_t obj;
    uint16_t xs;
    uint16_t ys;
    uint16_t xe;
    uint16_t ye;
    uint8_t clr;
    uint8_t tsz;
    uint8_t tid;
} tRecord;

struct Record recordsOut[MAX_RECORDS];
```

**Main Loop:**

```
void loop() {
    if (IsNetworkAlertState == 0) {
        if (setupProg[0].gid == 255 || setupProg[0].bnr == 255 || recordsOut[0].id == 255) {
            if (IsNoSetupAlertState == 0) {
                IsNoSetupAlertState = 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (IsNoSetupAlertState == 1) {
                IsNoSetupAlertState = 0; // Nothing to alert 
                RefreshScreen(); //Redraw data on screen after the setup is done!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Data recieved from Serial:**

```
const char* json = "{\"id\":1,\"sec\":1,\"obj\":1,\"xs\":1,\"ys\":0,\"xe\":158,\"ye\":62,\"clr\":0,\"tsz\":0,\"tid\":-1}";
```

**Caller:**

This is called maybe 20 times in order to store all the data.
Finally, it is written to non-volatile memory.

```
ApplyDesignSettings(json);
```

**Function to store incoming data:**

```
void ApplyDesignSettings(char buffer[]) {

    const size_t bufferSize = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(10) + 70;
    DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(bufferSize);

    if (IsDebugOn == 1) {
        Serial.print("buffer:");
        Serial.println(buffer);
    } 

    JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(const_cast<char*>(buffer));
    if (!root.success()) {
        Serial.println("parseObject() failed#1");
        return;
    }

    uint8_t id = root["id"];
    uint8_t sec = root["sec"];
    uint8_t obj = root["obj"];
    uint16_t xs = root["xs"];
    uint16_t ys = root["ys"];
    uint16_t xe = root["xe"];
    uint16_t ye = root["ye"];
    uint8_t clr = root["clr"];
    uint8_t tsz = root["tsz"];
    uint8_t tid = root["tid"];

    int ref = id;
    int idx = ref - 1;
    recordsOut[idx].id = id;
    recordsOut[idx].sec = sec;
    recordsOut[idx].obj = obj;
    recordsOut[idx].xs = xs;
    recordsOut[idx].ys = ys;
    recordsOut[idx].xe = xe;
    recordsOut[idx].ye = ye;
    recordsOut[idx].clr = clr;
    recordsOut[idx].tsz = tsz;
    recordsOut[idx].tid = tid; 
}
```

So far so good. I'm happy with this so far.
And here is the "**but**";

Sometimes, after flashing some ATmega2560 and pushing the data mentioned above, it misses/overwrites/removes first index of the *struct* array and I found it empty (255)
although the rest of the records are fine.

**This is the outcome:**

With for-loop debugging I get that below. This happens only for some of the ATmega2560's.

(Note that: After ID:8 (index 7) are all empty which is expected in this given sample)

```
========================================
Design data in non-volatile memory:
========================================
id:255, sec:255, obj:255
id:2, sec:1, obj:2
id:3, sec:1, obj:3
id:4, sec:1, obj:3
id:5, sec:2, obj:1
id:6, sec:2, obj:2
id:7, sec:2, obj:3
id:8, sec:2, obj:3
id:255, sec:255, obj:255
id:255, sec:255, obj:255
id:255, sec:255, obj:255
id:255, sec:255, obj:255
id:255, sec:255, obj:255
id:255, sec:255, obj:255
id:255, sec:255, obj:255
id:255, sec:255, obj:255
id:255, sec:255, obj:255
id:255, sec:255, obj:255
id:255, sec:255, obj:255
id:255, sec:255, obj:255
========================================
```

**Normally first index should be seen like this;**

```
id:1, sec:1, obj:1
```

I hope I could explain enough to give you a clue what goes wrong?

I appreciate your inputs from now.

Comment: This seems to be C++.

Comment: Since 255 is for not-set records it may mean that your first record (index 0) is not written at all. That would happen if your `idx` never evaluates to 0. Did you check if `idx` is always calculated correctly? You also do not control where do you writing your data (e.g. think what happen if `idx` from JSON is bigger than `MAX_RECORDS`). How do you debug it - with hardware debugger? Have you stepped thru `ApplyDesignSettings` on your suspected board?

Comment: @Andy, thanks for the reminders. I have checked if that `idx` ever evaluates to `0`. And yes, it does. For the consideration of the size of the JSON, I don't take serious action for it yet as this is still a work in progress. I now depend on  `if (!root.success())`. It is throwing error when something goes wrong with JSON. But, this is not the case either because, for the test purposes, I makes sure I send verified JSON. 
I can't do hardware debug but software with Serial monitor and it works ok so far.

Comment: @Sener, I get your point, on AVR I never made HW debugger running under my Eclipse env on Win x64 so I used UART debugging too.
Maybe you can make temporary plumbing in `ApplyDesignSettings` and print some debug to serial on wrong conditions, like `idx` out of 0-19 range or `id` set to 255 etc?

Comment: Hmm, wait a sec... you said you have 255 in non-volatile memory? Do you save it to EEPROM in atmega?

Comment: First of all this becomes long shot for SO, as I start suspecting non-programming issue here :) Let see though. Is that EEPROM you saving to? Internal or external? Does your device do a lot of power cycles (on-off) meantime? When does this first-index-overriding happen exactly - after many runs? on the same board always? Is data lost after you flashing new code with EEPROM said to be left intact?

Comment: @Andy, 
    It is internal EEPROM.   
    I continuously send JSON lines from Serial to `ApplyDesignSettings`  one by one. Each are stored in the `recordsOut`. And once all the JSON lines are sent, I store `recordsOut` in EEPROM.  
    There is no power cycle in terms of on and off.  
    As I stated, this is working without a glitch on some ATmega2560's. This is really bugging me.

Comment: Do you have BOD enabled in MCU? If not you may have issue with [clobbering first byte](http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/458646#comment-458646) of EEPROM. You can isolate issue giving it a try and offset by one byte location of your data in EEPROM so you do not use first byte. Can you share your EEPROM read/write routines?

Comment: Yes, there is BOD enabled. I did it in the first place.

This is how I write to the EEPROM;  

`#define CONFIG_START 32  
EEPROM.updateBlock(CONFIG_START, recordsOut);`

(Btw, I believe we can't compose proper format in comments, can we?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163322/discussion-between-sener-and-andy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after narrowing down the code (almost 2000 lines) up to a certain point, I could solve it. Also thanks to @Andy helped me to continue looking here and there on this issue.

Inside the `Else` in the `Loop`, `RefreshScreen();` was reloading recordsOut from `EEPROM` again and this was overwriting struct array `recordsOut` and next rounds of JSON the data were continuing form there.

I have removed EEPROM reading functions from `RefreshScreen();` and it has started to work.